# Update chart with SetSourceData in a chart sheet

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have an embedded chart in the sheet "Daten_G9-G10". In the same sheet there's the name "Chart9", which is a dynamic range:

=OFFSET('Daten_G9-G10'!$G$31;0;0;MAX('Daten_G9-G10'!$F$31:$F$51)+1;COUNTA('Daten_G9-G10'!$G$30:$AAA$30))

My goal is to update the chart's data range.

```
Sub UpdateChartSourceData()
  With ActiveSheet
   .ChartObjects(1).Chart.SetSourceData _
   Source:=.Range("Chart9"), _
   PlotBy:=xlRows
  End With
End Sub
```

This macro worked well so far. But I've moved the chart into a new sheet: "G9". That's where my problem begins: "Runtime error '438', Object doesn't support this property or method".

How do I have to adjust the macro that I can update this chart, still referring to the name in the sheet "Daten_G9-G10" as the chart's data range?

Comment: You ran the macro on the sheet with the chart right?

Comment: First yes. But now the former (embedded) chart is a chart sheet itself. I would like to run the macro on any sheet, if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

RIght now, your code only refers to `ActiveSheet`, which is causing an error probably because your chart is on the ActiveSheet, but the data is on another sheet.

Try this:

```
Sub UpdateChartSourceData()
  ' ## Modify the next line to refer to your chart sheet's name:
  With Worksheets("_Sheet_With_Chart_")
      .ChartObjects(1).Chart.SetSourceData _
          Source:=Worksheets("Daten_G9-G10").Range("Chart9"), _
          PlotBy:=xlRows
  End With
End Sub
```

**Update from comments**

If dealing with a *Chart Sheet*, modify to use the `Sheets` collection (`Worksheets` will raise an error)

```
Sub UpdateChartSourceData()
  ' ## Modify the next line to refer to your chart sheet's name:
  With Sheets("_Sheet_With_Chart_")
          .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Daten_G9-G10").Range("Chart9"), _
          PlotBy:=xlRows
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: okay I've changed the code. unfortunately I got a new error: "The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type." Is it because "G9" is a chart sheet? thanks in advance

Comment: For a chart Sheet you don't need `.ChartObjects(1).Chart` just use `.SetSourceData`

Comment: @thoscha you'll also have to refer to `Sheets(_chartsheet_name)` instead of `Worksheets`. I've updated my answer above :)