# Select data range for a chart from different sheet using VBA (EXCEL)

Tags: vba, excel, charts

How can I select data range for a chart from different sheet using VBA? Suppose that data sheet name is `data_sheet`, chart sheet name is `chart_sheet`, and my data range is `A1:A20`. How can I do this in excel? I checked [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388270/setting-a-chart-source-data-based-on-a-variable-cell-range-in-vba) but didn't work for different sheets. Otherwise, I checked [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630091/update-chart-with-setsourcedata-in-a-chart-sheet) but returned this error: `Subscript out of range`:

```
 With Worksheets("chart_sheet")
       ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("data_sheet").Range("A1:A20")
 End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `"chart_sheet"` is the name of your `Chart` and `"data_sheet"` is the name of your `Worksheet`, I think you want to do the following:

```
Charts("chart_sheet").SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("data_sheet").Range("A1:A20")
```

---

Your `With` block was not doing anything useful - the purpose of a `With` block is to allow you to just type `.` as a shortcut for something like `Worksheets("data_sheet").`.

So something like:

```
With Sheets("chart_sheet")
    .SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("data_sheet").Range("A1:A20")
End With
```

would work, because the `.SetSourceData` is an abbreviation of `Sheets("chart_sheet").SetSourceData`.  (Notice also that the `Sheets` collection contains both `Worksheets` and `Charts` objects, so `Charts("chart_sheet")` and `Sheets("chart_sheet")` both point to the same thing.)

---

`ActiveChart` refers to the currently active chart, just as `ActiveSheet` returns to the currently sheet.  If you don't have a chart active when that piece of code executes, you will get an error.

So the following piece of code would also probably have worked for you:

```
    Sheets("chart_sheet").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("data_sheet").Range("A1:A20")
```

Answer (score 1):

as chart_sheet is probably not a worksheet, did you try this ?

```
with sheets("chart_sheet")
```

Comment: did you verify that chart_sheet does exist ?

Comment: Returned error: `Object variable or With block variable not set` in this line `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("data_sheet").Range("A1:A20")`